# Most efficient way to build cost matrix for linear sum assignment?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Suppose we want to solve a linear sum assignment with scipy and the cost for the assignment can be build from Euclidean distances.

Thus, out of `m` workers `W=[j_1, ..., j_m]` and `n` tasks `T=[t_1, ..., t_n]`, the cost matrix is given by

```py
cost_matrix = np.array([
    [np.linalg.norm(x - y) for x in W] for y in T
])
```

This looks computationally heavy and not very efficient. Is there a numpy/scipy way to do this better and faster?

---

Working example:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment

np.random.seed(0)

# define tasks 
t = np.random.rand(5)

# define workers
w = np.random.rand(3)

cost_matrix = np.array([[np.linalg.norm(x-y) for x in w] for y in t])
```

```
>>> linear_sum_assignment(cost_matrix)
(array([1, 2, 4]), array([2, 0, 1]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is `cdist`. [Scipy cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html)

```
Y = cdist(XA, XB, 'euclidean')
```

Here is your example with working code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

np.random.seed(0)

# define tasks 
t = np.random.rand(5)

# define workers
w = np.random.rand(3)

# cost_matrix = np.array([[np.linalg.norm(x-y) for x in w] for y in t])  
cost_matrix = cdist(np.array([t]).T, np.array([w]).T, 'euclidean')
linear_sum_assignment(cost_matrix)
```

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most efficient way but iteration is passed on to numpy so this may be faster:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment

np.random.seed(0)

# define tasks 
t = np.random.rand(5)

# define workers
w = np.random.rand(3)

W, T = np.meshgrid(w, t)
cost_matrix = abs(T-W)
```

Comment: Why not just broadcast the arrays together?

Comment: Try this: `t.reshape(-1, 1) - w`. That won't make full arrays for anything but the output.